# How to add data to database and show on admin page with calculation

Tags: python, django

```
From Django.db import models

Class multi(models.Model):    
    Varone = models.Integer()
    Vartwo = varone * 2
```

How to do calculations in this class and show that calculations in the admin page of Django.

I tried to Google couldn't find answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to override the save method

```
class Multi(models.Model):
    var_one = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "first number")
    var_two = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name = "second number")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.var_two = self.var_one * 2 
        super(Multi,self).save()

    def __str__(self):
        return "multi method => {0} * 2 = {1}".format(self.var_one, self.var_two)
```

add this to **admin.py**

```
from .models import Multi

admin.site.register(Multi)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked really nice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, python has defined syntax and you should follow those things.
You could display the `var_2` by defining a `property` as below,

```
from django.db import models


class Multi(models.Model):
    var_1 = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def var_2(self):
        return self.var_1 * 2
```

Then override the `admin` as (change your `admin.py` )

```
from django.contrib import admin


class MultiAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'var_1', 'var_2')


admin.site.register(Multi, MultiAdmin)
```

You will get the [output as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjZnT.png)

Comment: Beautiful!! Thank you so much for your help. It Worked!!

Comment: I am not able to change the var_2 in the admin. Only the var_1 is editable.

Comment: Yeah... Your post/question indicates the `var_2` should be double of `var_1`. Which means, the `var_1` is the **independent variable** and `var_2` is the **dependent variable**, depends on the value of `var_1`

Comment: So, According to your comment, the question/original post logic will fails

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific while asking the question. I liked the way how you used the @property to make things really easy. Can I request to show me your way of editing the var_2. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you can't edit `var_2` if you're using `property`. If you wish to do so, better you edit your question, and add more specific details about your requirement